# CSS property to allow div to grow to full height of parent element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I have a component that has tabs (categories that can be expanded) and then lists (which appear to the right) - I've been really struggling with one aspect of the behaviour:

How can I allow `list-container` to "grow/expand" to the full height of `container` - so that the top of list always renders horizontally level with the first `heading-tab`?

Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

I'm actually using Styled Components with React, so the code snippet below is an attempt to replicate the DOM behaviour (array is mapped through and snippet (component) is returned for each item in array)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.heading-tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  max-height: 72px;
  width: 360px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.heading-text {
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.list-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.panel-container{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading-tab">
    <p class="heading-text">Heading One</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="heading-tab">
    <p class="heading-text">Heading Two</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="heading-tab">
    <p class="heading-text">Heading Three</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container">
    <div class="panel-container">
        <ul>
          <li>List items</li>
          <li>List items</li> 
          <li>List items</li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/simoncunningham/pen/mdwMgyL

Comment: will work one up & update!

Comment: this is a working example of the issue: https://codepen.io/simoncunningham/pen/mdwMgyL

replicated as best as possible - an array is mapped over and the code block in the question is returned for each item in the array. my codepen demos how that markup looks in the DOM.